# CSS Circle Mods in WordPress, where to insert code?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, templates, geometry

I have been trying for days to figure this out, I would be ever so grateful for some guidance.
I am trying to re-create the black circle, along with the mm/dd/yy, as shown in this theme: http://www.bluchic.com/how-to-change-header-text-to-a-logo-image-for-adelle-theme

so i grabbed the following code

```
} .post-date {
background: #000;
border-radius: 100px;
float: left;
font-size: 12px;
font-size: 1.2rem;
line-height: 1.1;
margin-right: 0.667em;
padding: 0.95em 1.05em;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 48px;
}
.post-date a {
color: #ddd;
}
.post-date span {
display: block;
}
.post-date .entry-day {
color: #fff;
font-size: 21px;
font-size: 2.1rem;
}
```

I would like to place it into this theme: http://sandbox.erinchambers.com/

however, I have been away from CSS for the last few years, and below is the snippet of code I think I should be working with? I'm very confused as the CSS versions seem to be different?

```
/* .article */

.article .article-content {width: 680px; float: right;}
  .article .post-header {margin-bottom: 30px; padding-top: 5px; border-top: 5px solid #000; border- bottom: 1px solid #000;}
  .article .post-meta {width: 240px; float: left; overflow: hidden;}
  .article ul.post-info-meta {overflow: hidden; font-size: .9em; margin: 5px 0; list-style: none;}
  .article ul.post-info-meta span {text-transform: uppercase; display: block; font-weight: 700;}
  .article ul.post-info-meta li {margin-bottom: 1px; padding: 0 0 0px 0px;}
```

I'm not sure where I should be editing the code in my stylesheet, if I should be making a child theme to do this, or if i also have to write in some additional HTML or PHP? And if so WHERE should I insert it?

Comment: use div to create circle!!!

Comment: I've only lightly edited wordpress templates a couple of times but I think you're on the right track. I believe you'll need to do two things. **1.** create a new div (for the circle) in the php page template within the area that creates the 'post header' divs. **2.** create a new class for the circle. You've found the right part of the css and you have the necessary code above to create a circle `border-radius`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know a little bit of HTML and CSS you just need to pick up a guide for few simple pointers on how to edit a Wordpress theme.

Smart thing to do would be to copy the style you wish to change and download it on your local machine so you would get familiar with the assets of the theme.

Adding a circle, in your case is very simple

```
.post-date time
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

To explain what I did there

- you already have a **li** tag with class called "**.post-date**"
- in that **li** tag you have two more child tags **span** and **time**
- we target the class that has a specific child and assign properties to it

In shortest of terms, if you would like to go down and dirty. You could just open **style.css** inside your current theme, without copying anything, and just add the code above at the bottom of the file.